# jQuery изменить определенные значения в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

Здравствуйте!
Есть такой линк:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:add('value1', 'opt1', 'value2', 'opt2', 'value3', 'value4'); return:false;">+</a>
```

Необходимо по событию поменять только opt1 и opt2, все остальные значения постоянные. Таких ссылок может быть любое количество. Изначально ссылка генерируется на php с заранее заданными параметрами и выглядит так:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:add('555', '25', 'http://url', '280', 'text', 'name'); return:false;">+</a>
```

Пробовал так:

```
$('.target').change(function() {
$(this).next('a').attr("onclick", "javascript:add('" +opt1+ "', '25', 'http://url', '"+ opt2 + "', 'text', 'name'); return:false;") });
```

Но данный код будет работоспособным только для одной ссылки т.к. другие имеют отличные от этой постоянные атрибуты.
Предполагаю, что надо сначала получить attr("onclick") и разбить параметры на постоянные и те которые будут меняться.

Comment: А изменить на PHP нельзя код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужны регулярки. **Исправленный вариант:**

```js
$('a').each(function(id, el) {
  var $el = $(el);
  var onClickSrc = $el.attr('onclick');
  var param1 = '"par1"';
  var param2 = '"par2"';

  var params = onClickSrc.match(/'[^']+'/g);

  params[1] = param1;
  params[3] = param2;

  onClickSrc = onClickSrc.replace(
    /\([^\)]+\)/,
    '(' + params.join(', ') + ')'
  );

  $el.attr('onclick', onClickSrc);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:add('value1', 'opt1', 'value2', 'opt2', 'value3', 'value4'); return:false;">+</a>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:add('value1', 'opt1', 'value2', 'opt2', 'value31', 'value41'); return:false;">+</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но ваш код меняет первые два параметра 'value1', 'opt1', а надо opt1 и opt2

Comment: Исправил решение.

Comment: Понял направление :), а если дополнительно рассмотреть вариант, когда в onclick есть параметры без кавычек, например: document.getElementById('element').value